# How to move values from a private class to another?

Tags: java, class, return, call, private

i'm a novice in java and i don't know how to call a variable from a private class to another.
Currently i'm using NetBeans 8.1 and here's the class from which i wanna take the values

```
public class Mars {
public static String name;
private static int fuel; 
private static int AI;
private static int tecnology;
public void setName(String nm)
{
    name = nm;
}
public void setFuel(int fl)
{
    fuel = fl;
}
public void setAI(int ai)
{
    AI = ai;
}
public void setTecnology(int tc)
{
    tecnology = tc;
}

public String getName()
{
    return name;
}
public int getFuel()
{
    return fuel;
}
public int getAI()
{
    return AI;
}
public int getTecnology()
{
    return tecnology;
}

private static class name {
public name(){
    name = "unknown";
}
}
private static class fuel{
public fuel() {
    fuel = 50;
    if ((fuel >100) || (fuel <0))
    {System.out.println("\nError!");
                          System.exit(0);}}}

private static class AI {
public AI() {
    AI = 5;
    if ((AI >10) || (AI <1))
    {System.out.println("\nError!");
                          System.exit(0);}}}
private static class tecnologiy {
public tecnologiy() {
    tecnology = 5;
    if ((tecnology >10) || (tecnology <1))
    {System.out.println("\nError");
                          System.exit(0);}}}
```

}

And here is the class where i want to put the values:

```
public class Space_Battle {

public static void main(String[] args) {
Mars Call1 = new Mars();
System.out.println("\nThe alien named " + Mars.name + " joined the battle" );
}
```

}

Naturally every correction will be very appreciate! :-D
P.S. I'm sorry if this question is ridicoulos.

Comment: `Call1.getName()` (not `Mars.name`). Also, remove the `static`(s) from your *instance* fields.

Comment: Thanks to everyone :-D

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to this...

```
public class Space_Battle {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Mars mars = new Mars();
        System.out.println("\nThe alien named " + mars.getName() + " joined the battle");
    }
```

When you create an instance of an object, you should access it via secure accessors i.e. getter methods, getName(), etc.

And remove the static declaration from your private variables.

Answer (score 0):

You cant directly set values to private variables from another class, thats why they are private.

You **HAVE** to instantiate an object of the said class.

Example:

```
Mars call1= new Mars();
```

then you can set values to that object.

```
call1.setName("whatever");
```

then to get the value of the object just use the getter.

```
 call1.getName();
```

then to print it:

```
System.out.println("\nThe alien named " + call1.getName() + " joined the battle" );
```

Also, remove the static from your variables.

I would also encourage you to read about the "this" keyword.

I recommend you to read this documentation:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/object.html

Comment: No, technically the variables could be static in which case you don't have to instantiate anything. Also, you should mention getters, because that would be the actual answer to the question.

Comment: im pretty sure he doesnt really now what a static variable is since he mentions he is a novice, a basic bean should not have static getters and setters.

Comment: Right, but if this was a utility class or something, then everything would be static. It's good to simplify things sometimes, but that doesn't mean omitting information that could help people really understand why the problem was happening. Just trying to give some advice. Good job :)